# Wiring multiple AsyncCallbacks from different clients to same instance Worker thread.(.NET/C#)

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, asynchronous

I have a unique problem here which I am unable to resolve. I have got a Webservice. 
A method in the webservice, creates a Worker thread to perform a long running operation.

```
void KickStartLongRunningOperation()
```

But the problem is that multiple clients depends on completion of this thread.

I also have a BeginLongRunninOperation(AsyncCallback callback, AsyncState), and EndLongRunningOp... pair of WebMethod.

Now the desired behaviour is that all the AsyncCallback from different clients should be called when the main worker thread(LongRunningOperation) completes.

How to do this? Is it possible? To illustrate a call sequence:

- client 1 calls -> void KickStartLongRunningOperation() -> Main Worker Thread starts (Only one instance)
- client 1 calls -> BeginXXX supplies AsyncCallback as parameter (This should ideally wire this AsyncCallback to the same instance of LongRunning Worker thread)
- client 2 calls -> BeginXXX supplies AsyncCallback as parameter (This should ideally wire this AsyncCallback to the same instance of LongRunning Worker thread)
- client 3 calls -> BeginXXX supplies AsyncCallback as parameter (This should ideally wire this AsyncCallback to the same instance of LongRunning Worker thread)
  ...

---

### Main Worker Thread completes

- AsyncCallback on Client 1 instance/thread should be called
- AsyncCallback on Client 2 instance/thread should be called
- AsyncCallback on Client 3 instance/thread should be called

Instead of polling, I would like to do it though APM, but I am not sure as how to wire multiple AsyncCallbacks from different instance of clients to the same worker thread.

Comment: Probably using the `Task` class and a job manager would be appropriate here? The job manager keeps a reference to the running task and the clients do `manager.Task.ContinueWith(callback)`.

Comment: Note this is in webservice. So if I take the approach you suggest, client has to also use Task parallel library?

Comment: What is Job Manager you suggest here? Is it part of Task Parallel Library, or my own job manager implementation. Can you point me out to some links or existing implementation code in the net.

Comment: I mean your own implementation, which i called a "job manager". It's just something to hold and synchronize the reference to the running task. Yes, i mean the `Task` class from Task Parallel Library.